# Creating Visual Studio Error List Messages

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, message, error-list

Is there any way to create a custom message in the Visual Studio error list? I'm looking at VS 2010 and 2012.

For generating errors, it's a simple `#error text`.
For generating warnings it's `#pragma warning ("text")`.
For printing a message to the Output window, it's `#pragma message("text")`

There's little or no documentation on how to create a information message in the Error List. Anyone know if it is possible?
I'd prefer if no VS addons would be used, but if there is a way with those, that would be fine too.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly this may help: [Formatting the Output of a Custom Build Step or Build Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxkt8b26(v=vs.100).aspx)

or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-diagnostic-format-for-tasks?view=vs-2022

> Formatting the Output of a Custom Build Step or Build Event
>
> If the output of a custom build step or build event is formatted
> correctly, users get the following benefits:
>
> - Warnings and errors are counted in the Output window.
> - Output appears in the Task List window.
> - Clicking on the output in the Output window displays the appropriate topic.
> - F1 operations are enabled in the Task List window or Output window.
>
> The format of the output should be:
>
> ```
> {filename (line# [, column#]) | toolname} :
>
> [any text] {error | warning} code####: localizable string
> ```

Answer (score 0):

And this macro is a possible implementation of what Rost linked to :

```
#define COMBINE_NAMES_HELPER_6(a,b,c,d,e,f)                   a##b##c##d##e##f
#define COMBINE_NAMES_6(a,b,c,d,e,f)                          COMBINE_NAMES_HELPER_6(a,b,c,d,e,f)

#define FILE_LINE_FUNC_STR(msg)   ( COMBINE_NAMES_6(__FILE__, "(",STRING( __LINE__), "): ", __FUNCTION__, " "msg) )
#define COMPILER_MSG(msg)         message FILE_LINE_FUNC_STR(msg)
```

Comment: The __FUNC__ is not necessary. It's just the code I use in my projects in order to get clearer messages.